# Help building a square box under my complex 3D model!

Tags: modeling, extrude

My 3D model has the complex geometry of a small, rocky river. To be able to import it into my fluid dynamics software, I need the boundaries of the model to be rectangular.
I am looking for something similar to the table in the attached picture. This will include extending the riverbanks a bit so that they create a straigt edge (as the river is not straight in itself). Then increase the depth of the model such that all faces are flat rectangles except the top one, which contains the river texture. 
Is this feasable? Any help or tip would be greatly appreciated!
[image: Angled view of the river][image: Top view of the river][image: Table example]

Comment: I've hard time to understand what the result could be? Because the model is not flat at all but the table is. Could you give an example of the result on some small part of the model? Is it just make so that the mesh relies on a bottom part that is a parallelepiped?

Comment: What I am going for is easest to imagine as a solid block with the river carved into the top face of it, with 90 deg corners and straight faces. To create my mesh for the fluids simulation, the abosute easiest is to have a block tightly hug the model to determine the boundary conditions. That is why i want to create this block shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach gives you an object with the river bed on the bottom side and a volume with planar surface.

[image]

First load the model of the riverbed, then switch to edit mode and select all vertices <kbd>A</kbd>.

[image]

Then extrude the surface either with the extrude tool on the left hand side or by pressing <kbd>E</kbd>. Then move the mouse cursor upwards so that the model is a bit taller then the desired end result.

[image]

The following steps depend on whether you want to modify only the Z-direction or if you want intersect the entire model with another volume.

If you just want to modify the Z-direction press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd> with the extruded part still selected. This will scale the Z-direction to zero making it completely flat. You may have to adjust the Z position to the desired height by pressing <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>. Then you should be done, unless you want to flip the normals which is described in the last step below.

If you'd like to intersect the model with a cubic volume you need to do the following steps.

Next add a Cube in object mode and scale it so the desired section of the riverbed is inside the volume. The height of the Cube should be the height you want the final model to have.

[image]

Now apply a *Boolean modifier* to the Cube.

[image]

Set the *Operation* to *Intersection*  and set the object to your riverbed model.

[image]

Now you can remove or hide the other model and just keep the result of the boolean operation. If you need the normals to face inwards for the simulation you can switch to the edit mode and recalculate the normals inside (*Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Inside*) or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: you could also just select all the top vertices and scale them to 0 on the Z axis rather than booleaning.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough reply! This was great! By moving the box so that it covered the top part of the model instead of the bottom part, I was able to achieve what I wanted in the z-axis. Can I follow the same steps to additionally extrude and modify in x and y directions?

Comment: Is there for example a way to use the result i got from following your steps as a mould to "press" into a big cube, as you would a signet ring into hot wax?

Comment: @Sazerac you're completely right. Made an edit. The solution with the boolean is meant for the case when you want to modify x and y as well.

Comment: @MadsIvarson If I understand you correctly, then yes that's possible.  First you create the extruded version of the riverbed, then you make a large cube the size of your "wax". Place the riverbed were it should indent the "wax". Then add a boolean modifier to the cube, select the operation "subtract" and the riverbed as object.

Comment: That worked like a charm! This is exactly what i was looking for! Thank you so much! I tried attaching a photo of the result ![Valid XHTML](https://imgur.com/a/k5m27Jl).